# How to apply multiple criteria condition using MogoTemplate

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria, mongotemplate

I want to apply multiple condition on Criteria but andOperator seconds String gives error

mongoTemplate.find(new Query(new Criteria().andOperator
                (Criteria.where("notificationTime").gte(DateTime.now().minusMinutes(15).millisOfSecond())
                        .andOperator(Criteria.where("failureCount")).gt(3))) );

Comment: Could you post the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criteria definition looks okay. However, one of the reasons why it might give you an error is, you are not passing the second argument to `find` method. Have a look at the javadoc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#find-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-java.lang.Class-):

> **public  List find(Query query,**
>                           **Class entityClass)**
>
> collection for the entity class to a List of the specified type.

Try the following:

```
mongoTemplate.find(new Query(new Criteria().andOperator (Criteria.where("notificationTime")
  .gte(DateTime.now().minusMinutes(15).millisOfSecond())
  .andOperator(Criteria.where("failureCount")).gt(3))), Response.class);
```

Where `Response.class` is the class you want to cast your response to.